# Separate Totals row from tablesorter in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, tablesorter

I am using tablesorter in Django and would like to separate the Totals row from being sorted from the whole table. As of now, if I sort any column, the totals row gets sorted with it as well.

Currently, my table is being produced with the "Totals" Row coming in last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you problem is only with tablesorter (not with django). The easiest way to leave the last row unsorted (as in a totals row) is to organize you table with thead, tbody and tfoot. Something like:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
    ....
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr> ... </tr>
    <tr> ... </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
       <td>Total</td><td> ... </td> ...
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

The row nested in the tfoot tag won't be sorted.

Comment: Right, I'm simply passing in a list of items such as a = [1,2,3,4]
and in the actual html page, I am running a for look that pop's each item from that list the last one being totals...

Comment: OK. Use {% if forloop.last %} in django to identify the last item and then give it the right sintax i.e. <tfoot>